# Battery went dead, charged it, took it and had it, along with alternator and starter checked, its good. Now it wont start again

Tags: battery, starting

Battery went dead, charged it, took it and had it checked, its good.  Also tested Alternator and Starter.  Got home turned it off and on and it started.  Waited 30 minutes and it will not start again.  Any idea what to check next?

Comment: What happens when you turn the key?

Comment: The dash lights come on and when I turn the key they go off and on.  It clicks like the battery is low(dead).

Comment: It was the Camshaft position sensor. It was all gunked up.

Comment: Deana, there is no way that the Cam Position Sensor could have caused the fault you described in your comment above.  Who told you that the sensor was at fault?

Comment: The auto parts place that tested the other things.  She said it could be the camshaft position sensor.  That if it's going bad and gets stuck it can drain the battery.  That is the only thing we worked on so it had to be what the problem was.

Comment: The cam position sensor would not have power to it while the ignition is off, so I don't see how it could flatten the battery.  My guess would be that they cleaned some contacts and then charged you for a cam position sensor.

Comment: Of course, you are right... After a few days and not constantly driving it the battery is losing charge again... ugh

Comment: My husband, that is not a mechanic, thinks it may be the voltage regulator.  Is that possible?

Comment: Finding a fault like this can be difficult.  You really need to measure the current being drawn from the battery while different circuits are disconnected by pulling fuses.  It is possible that the regulator in the alternator is faulty, if that is what he meant, but it could also be many other things.  Not starting again after 30 minutes as in your question points more to a faulty battery, alternator or a bad connection on either.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely fault here is that your battery terminal connectors are dirty or loose.  Disconnect them from the battery and clean them and the battery terminals with an abrasive (sand paper, wire brush), then reconnect them.

If this doesn't fix it, you need to check the battery voltage using a voltmeter, both with the ignition off (should be at least 12v) and if possible while trying to start it (should stay above 9v).

If the voltage is below 12 with the ignition off, then the battery is probably faulty.

Comment: Agreed, also worth checking that the ignition switch itself and the thin (usually blue) exciter cable for the starter motor is intact.